# Drop-down in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Drop-down is not showing in browser, it's only displaying the options name without the drop-down list.

I also want to call a JavaScript function on select of drop-down and on the next page. How can I display selected option that user select from drop down?
Code of my page is:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<form:select path="phone">
    <form:option value="samsung">SAMSUNG</form:option>
    <form:option value="nokia">NOKIA</form:option>
    <form:option selected="selected" value="htc">HTC</form:option>
    <form:option value="iphone">IPHONE</form:option>
</form:select>
```

And when I run my project it's showing all the values without display drop down list:

[image: Result of my code is]

Comment: A more relevant piece of information would be how the page source looks like, a screenshot adds no value.

Comment: looks like your server is not processing the jsp properly. what does the html source look like?

Comment: problem has solved by adding 
 <%@taglib uri="springframework.org/tags/form"; prefix="form"%>  in jsp i forgot to add this line .... btw thanx for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form:select path="state">
<form:options items="${lang_choose_option}" />
</form:select>
```

and your output will be:

```
<select name="state">
    <option value="1">Alabama</option>
    <option value="2">Alaska</option>
    <option value="3">Arizona</option>
    <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="5">California</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select path="phone">  
      <form:option value="samsung">SAMSUNG</form:option>  
      <form:option value="nokia">NOKIA</form:option>  
      <form:option selected="selected" value="htc">HTC</form:option>  
      <form:option value="iphone">IPHONE</form:option>  
</select> 


its showing blank drop down

Comment: why you are making options as form elements? Put the "select" tag in "form" tag.

Comment: OR you can do like this as well `<select form="form_id">`

Comment: i dont want to use html i want to do like
 <form:select path="phone" items="${lang_choose_option}">  
        </form:select>
i will pass some object through controller
so that i can polulate the dropdown dynamically using spring mvc

Comment: I have edited the answer now please check @KunalBatra

Comment: should i  pass list in  object lang_choose_option or should i pass map in lang_choose_option object

Comment: You can pass any of them.

Comment: : hi i found out my mistake 
i didnt add 
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
in my jsp page 

now this code is working fine 

 <form:select path="state">
<form:options items="${state}" />
</form:select>

Comment: Great. You can accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: edit your comment 
it should be 
<form:select path="lang_choose_option">
<form:options items="${lang_choose_option}" />
</form:select>
instead of 

<form:select path="state">
<form:options items="${lang_choose_option}" />
</form:select>
select path and options items shuld be in my code

Comment: @ MDaniyal : thanx for your precious time